# Perl: Can't call method "catfile" without a package or object reference

Tags: perl, file-io, perl-module, cat

I'm trying to use 'cat file' in my Perl module like below,

```
my $batch_dir = '/home/lsubramaniyam/xxx';
    my $receive_file = $batch_dir->catfile("Recieve_file.txt");
```

But, on executing the script, I'm getting error as

```
Can't call method "catfile" without a package or object reference
```

I have included packages related to the file handles and OOPS,

```
 use IO::All;
    use IO::Socket;
    use IO::Socket::SSL;
    use Moo;
    use MooX::HandlesVia;
    use MooX::Options (
        protect_argv       => 0,
        prefer_commandline => 1,
    );
    use MooX::Types::MooseLike::Base
        qw(Bool Enum HashRef Int InstanceOf Maybe Str);
    use File::Spec;
```

Please help me on steps to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/File::Spec) more carefully. Lines 4 and 5:

```
use File::Spec;
$x=File::Spec->catfile('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Comment: Thank you. I was new to Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `catfile()` as a method here. Methods can only be called on classes or objects. `$batch_dir` is just a string. You can't call methods on a string (that's what your error is saying).

The documentation for [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) shows `catfile()` being called as a class method. So you want something like this:

```
my $batch_dir = '/home/lsubramaniyam/xxx';
my $receive_file = File::Spec->catfile($batch_dir, 'Recieve_file.txt');
```

Comment: Thank you. I was new to Perl.